# Laravel CRUD update after inserting user password

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, crud, laravel-blade

So, I'm not using ajax on my CRUD, and I have this on my blade to delete a user:

```
{!! Form::open(['style' => 'display: inline-block;', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'onsubmit' => 'return confirm(\'' . trans('admin.users-index-are_you_sure') . '\');',  'route' => array('users.destroy', $query->id)]) !!}
{!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>'.trans('admin.users-index-delete'), ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger'] )  !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

At this moment I'm returning a javascript alert with 'are you sure?' before deleting, but I need to have a form or a box that the user inserts his password.
My question is, theres any Laravel fancy way to do this?
How can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't think that Laravel has a built-in way to do this. Probably need to implement the flow yourself.

Comment: Do you think I have to confirm this in the controller?

Comment: Many sites I've visited redirect to a "confirm password" site and then go forward to the real request. My guess is you'd have a middleware like "requiresconfirmation" which does that while keeping the real target URL somewhere for you to move to after its done. I'm not a middleware expert but you can check https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware for more info

Comment: In addition to @apokryfos comment, there's a package that exists for this already: https://github.com/mpociot/reauthenticate

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Javascript then you should redirect the user to another view where you can ask for his password.

Otherwise you can change the approach, first you redirect and then you launch the js confirm to let the user there is no go back